# Регулярное выражение, которое требует обязательного наличия цифр и латинских букв и разрешает использование других символов из списка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать регулярное выражение, которое будет разрешать вводить символы из списка и требовать обязательного наличия латинских букв и цифр. (кириллицу и спецсимволы, если их нет в списке - нельзя)

Сейчас работает так, что запрещено все, кроме того, что указано в списке, но как сделать чтобы буквы и цифры были еще и обязательными?

```js
function test(value) {
  const passReg = /^[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\|[\]{}:;.,<>?]+$/;
  console.log(passReg.test(value));
}
```

```html
<input oninput=test(event.target.value)>
```

то есть при вводе 111 должна быть ошибка и при вводе Aaa или ф1111f тоже, а вот 111aaa должно пропускать

Comment: или же вы хотите что бы спецсимвол тоже был обязательным?

Comment: @SelectionForCollection нет только латиница и цифры. Тоже подумал, что можно два отдельных условия написать, но как написать регулярку, которая будет требовать обязательного наличия указанных символов - тоже не нашел. Т.е чтобы первая проверяла, что я не ввел ничего лишнего (ну в общей сейчас так и работает),  а вторая - что я ввел как минимум из требуемых символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте позитивный просмотр вперед
`(?=.*[A-Z])` - наличие буквы в верхнем регистре
`(?=.*[a-z])` - наличие буквы в нижнем регистре
`(?=.*\d)` - наличие цифры

```js
function test(value) {
  const passReg = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)^[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\|[\]{}:;.,<>?]+$/;
  console.log(passReg.test(value));
}
```

```html
<input oninput=test(event.target.value)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать так?

```js
function test(value) {
  const passReg = /^[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\|[\]{}:;.,<>?]+$/;
  console.log(passReg.test(value) && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value));
}
```

```html
<input oninput=test(event.target.value)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно было бы использовать 3 разных проверки, либо же использовать так называемые `lookahead-ы` - то есть опережающие или ретроспективные проверки.
В итоге ваша регулярка будет похожа на `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$`

UPD

Просто бы добавили все что можно использовать после лукахэдов..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2 - забыл прикрепить регулярку со скрина - `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*[a-zA-Z/d!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\|[\]{}:;.,<>?]$`

Bот [ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/QU3Zqk/1)

Comment: проверку прошел ф111aA